# Magento 2: custom form in custom module not sending email

Tags: php, magento2

I have a custom form within a custom module, and I need it to send an email. Currently, when I submit my form, the page reloads and I get no message. No errors in console. And no email is sent.

Here is the PHP code for my custom module.

Vendor/Module/Block/Index.php:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return '/customemail/index/post';
    }

}
```

Vender/Module/Controller/Index/Post.php:

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Controller\Index;

use Zend\Log\Filter\Timestamp;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_NAME = 'trans_email/ident_general/name';
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT_EMAIL = 'trans_email/ident_general/email';

    protected $_inlineTranslation;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_logLoggerInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        array $data = []

        )
    {
        $this->_inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_logLoggerInterface = $loggerInterface;
        $this->messageManager = $context->getMessageManager();


        parent::__construct($context);


    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try
        {
            // Send Mail
            $this->_inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

            $sender = [
                'name' => $post['name'],
                'email' => $post['email'],
                'phone' => $post['phone'],
                'numGuests' => $post['numGuests'],
                'eventType' => $post['eventType'],
                'eventDesc' => $post['eventDesc']
            ];

            $sentToEmail = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

            $sentToName = $this->_scopeConfig ->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);


            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('customemail_email_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => 'frontend',
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars([
                    'name'  => $post['name'],
                    'email'  => $post['email'],
                    'phone' => $post['phone'],
                    'numGuests' => $post['numGuests'],
                    'eventType' => $post['eventType'],
                    'eventDesc' => $post['eventDesc']
                ])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($sentToEmail,$sentToName)
                //->addTo('owner@example.com','owner')
                ->getTransport();

                $transport->sendMessage();

                $this->_inlineTranslation->resume();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Email sent successfully');
                $this->_redirect('/private-events');

        } catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_logLoggerInterface->debug($e->getMessage());
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Vender/Module/view/frontend/templates/customemail_index_index.phtml:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" name="customemaildata" method="post" id="contactForm-1" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' class="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="field event-type required">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php  echo __('Type of Event') ?>" name="eventType" id="eventType" title="<?php echo __('eventType') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field description">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea placeholder="Tell us about your event" name="eventDesc" id="eventDesc" title="<?php echo __('eventDesc') ?>" data-validate="{required:false}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="field name required">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php  echo __('Name') ?>" name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo __('Name') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field email required">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php  echo __('Email') ?>" name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>     
            <div class="field phone required">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php  echo __('Phone') ?>" name="phone" id="phone" title="<?php echo __('Phone') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field num-guests required">
                <div class="control">
                    <input placeholder="<?php  echo __('Number of Guests') ?>" name="numGuests" id="numGuests" title="<?php echo __('numGuests') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="actions-toolbar center">
                <div class="primary">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary button button--solid-dark button--wide">
                        <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My module contains the following files (which I am not providing code for initially because I believe the issue lies somewhere in the PHP):

```
Vender
 Module
  Block
   -Index.php
  Controller
   Index
    -Post.php
  etc
   frontend
    -routes.xml
   -email_templates.xml
   -module.xml
  view
   frontend
    email
     -customemail.phtml
    layout
     -customemail_index_index.xml
    templates
     -customemail_index_index.phtml
  -registration.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, I did solve my problem with the following edits.

**Vendor/Module/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

**Vender/Module/Controller/Index/Post.php**
The issue here was that my sender data was not correct. I changed / added this:

```
$senderName = $post['name'];
$senderEmail = $post['email'];

$sender = [
  'name' => $senderName,
  'email' => $senderEmail,
];
```

**Vender/Module/view/frontend/templates/customemail_index_index.phtml**
Here I changed my form action to this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'/customemail/index/post/';?>" name="customemaildata" method="post" id="privateForm-1" data-hasrequired="<?php echo __('* Required Fields') ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' class="form">
```